# Active Directory 2008 to 2003

Tags: active-directory

So my Active Directory setup is set to work for computers running Vista or higher. I didn't foresee the need to have a Windows Server 2003 computer on the domain, so how can I now be able to join the 2003 computer to the 2008 domain? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just join it to the domain.  The domain functional level is only for the versions of Windows that can be domain controllers on the domain.  You could join a Windows NT 4 machine to the domain if you wanted to.

Comment: Great, thank you for the answer. The server took a minute to join to the domain, but everything seems to be in order. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If you mean how do you add a new Domain Controller running Windows Server 2003 after you've raised the Domain/Forest functional level to Windows Server 2008, the short answer is you can't.

If you just mean a normal member server, just go ahead and join it - it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Mrdenny answer, the restriction applies to DOMAIN CONTROLLERS, not regular members.